# AngularJs convert $http POST to $resource POST

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I am looking for an example on how to POST data using $resource.  I currently have this working code using $http, but would like to simplify it using $resource.

```
return $http.post("http://localhost:8080/calculate", JSON.stringify(formData))
               .then(function (response) {
                    if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
                        return response.data;
                    } else {
                        // invalid response
                        return $q.reject(response.data);
                    }
                }, function (response) {
                    // something went wrong
                    return $q.reject(response.data);
                });
```

I've tried searching around for examples, but have not been able to find any that fit this case.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource has sample code demonstrating this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your resource like this:

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('MyResource', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('', {}, {
    'calculate': { method: 'POST', url: 'http://localhost:8080/calculate' }
  });
});
```

or this:

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('MyResource', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('http://localhost:8080/calculate', {}, {
    'calculate': { method: 'POST' }
  });
});
```

And then you can use it:

```
MyResource.calculate({}, JSON.stringify(formData), onSuccess, onError);
```

With first approach you can define different actions with different urls in single resource (`url` property), which can be useful sometimes, especially when API which you are using is not unified.

Second approach is better when you have the same endpoint and various request methods for it (like in regular RESTfull APIs). There you can just define them with different names (like get, update, delete, etc.).

You can also use resources in a way like:

```
var result = MyResource.calculate(JSON.stringify(formData));
```

It's also possible to get access to internal `$promise` so you can do some more complicated stuff.

What's important from my experience is that you should remember about `isArray: true` property, when your API returns JSON array.

All details are described here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: I was able to get this answer working, but had to fully qualify the url property inside calculate, since that overrides the resource url.  Without this change, all requests go to the same host and port as the web app.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I was writing this answer quickly without a change to test it and forgot about that. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You first create a $resource class representation for Calculate, as shown first.

This resource class has a save function that allows you POST data as you wish.

```
angular.module('myApp.services').factory('Calculate', function($resource) {
  return $resource('http://localhost:8080/calculate');
});

angular.module('myApp.controllers').controller('ResourceController',function($scope, Calculate) {
  $scope.calc = new Calculate(); //You can instantiate resource class

  $scope.calc.data = JSON.stringify(formData);

  Calculate.save($scope.calc, function() {
      // Callback function to run once the data is saved.
  });
});
```

Comment: I couldn't get this working.  The service always gets an empty request body.